# Import Last Auto-Saved Postman Config from Time Machine backup

Tags: postman

How do I import my last Postman config from a Time Machine backup?

By this, I mean the default collections and such that Postman loads when I open it (before the last backup), irrespective of the last json export backup.

Comment: Postman keeps its stuff in the **~/Library/Application Support/Postman** folder. You probably need to restore this whole folder from Time Machine to avoid any mismatched/out-of-sync files.

Comment: I tried putting the entire folder in the same location on the new install but postman does not seem to be reading from it even after restarting - how does one enable reading from an injected folder?